# Using Streams in Gatling repeat blocks

Tags: scala, gatling

I've come across the following code in a Gatling scenario (modified for brevity/privacy):

```
val scn = scenario("X")
  .repeat(numberOfLoops, "loopName") {
      exec((session : Session) => {
        val loopCounter = session.getTypedAttribute[Int]("loopName")
        session.setAttribute("xmlInput", createXml(loopCounter))
      })
      .exec(
        http("X")
         .post("/rest/url")
         .headers(headers)
         .body("${xmlInput}"))
      )
  }
```

It's naming the loop in the repeat block, getting that out of the session and using it to create a unique input XML. It then sticks that XML back into the session and extracts it again when posting it.

I would like to do away with the need to name the loop iterator and accessing the session.
Ideally I'd like to use a `Stream` to generate the XML.

But Gatling controls the looping and I can't recurse. Do I need to compromise, or can I use Gatling in a functional way (without vars or accessing the session)?

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, neither numberOfLoops nor createXml seem to depend on anything user related that would have been stored in the session, so the loop could be resolved at build time, not at runtime.

```
import com.excilys.ebi.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder

def addXmlPost(chain: ChainBuilder, i: Int) =
    chain.exec(
        http("X")
            .post("/rest/url")
            .headers(headers)
            .body(createXml(i))
    )

def addXmlPostLoop(chain: ChainBuilder): ChainBuilder =
    (0 until numberOfLoops).foldLeft(chain)(addXmlPost)
```

Cheers,

Stéphane

PS: The preferred way to ask something about Gatling is our Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gatling

Comment: I think, for myriad reasons, asking questions on stack overflow is going to help more people than asking questions on Gatling's Google Group.

Comment: Your point of view. Not mine since I had some answers downvoted, and even once removed by a moderator, even when the question was explicitly targeting Gatling and I'm the project leader.

Comment: Of course that's just my opinion, but the community feedback (usually) is still valuable even though it's your project right?  It may be the right answer but the feeling that there "should be a better answer" still helps - particularly because it is your project.  There are still lots of good reasons to use stack overflow instead.  For example, google groups is pretty unattractive and is difficult to find helpful information.  Stack overflow also has better exposure to a less segmented group of technologists who carry valuable influence.  Again, just my opinion.